# Capitalizing items in a dropdown box using Liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid, capitalization

First time using Liquid.. I am an old-time Vbasic programmer.
I had added some customization to our Shopify Store.  I have worked out the basic details for the mechanics of the code and have it working, but I would like the items to be properly capitalized when it creates the dropbox.

```
  {% if section.settings.show_collection_tags and section.settings.collection_tags == 'dropdown' %}
  {% if collection.url.size == 0 %}
  {% assign collection_url = routes.all_products_collection_url %}
  {% else %}
  {% assign collection_url = collection.url %}
  {% endif %}
  {% assign has_tags = false %}
  {% capture tags_html %}
  <span class="tags filter">
    <label for="filter-by">{{ 'collections.general.filter_by' | t }}:</label>
    <select id="filter-by" class="redirect">
      <option value="{{ collection_url }}">{{ 'collections.general.all_items' | t }}</option>
      {% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
      {% unless BadTags contains tag %}
        <option value="{{ collection_url }}/{{ tag | handle }}" {% if current_tags contains tag %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ tag }}</option>
      {% assign has_tags = true %}
      {% endunless %}
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </span>
  {% endcapture %}{% if has_tags %}{{ tags_html }}{% endif %}
  {% endif %}
```

I tried using `| Capitalize` following `{{{ tag | handle`  but that didn't work.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Not much cleared what you try to do, you need to capitalize the tag handle or something else?

Comment: I believe the Tag Handle is what the Dropbox is being populated with.  I am looking to have the entries in the dropbox capitalized.